# Java RDF validation

Tags: java, rdf

I have a RDF file containing some errors(probably unrecognized characters).
Is there any way to find these errors in Java?

Comment: That's a very broad question. What RDF parser are you using?

Comment: I am not using any RDF parser. I have tried using the SAXParser and javax.xml.validation.Validator but i needed to make a xsd for the RDF file, which I didn't succeed...

Comment: I don't think I can help you myself. But I think your question can be improved if you add a _small_ RDF file that demonstrates the problem. And maybe a snippet of Java code that shows what's going wrong, too. The key is to keep these examples as small as possible, to keep the attention of the readers.

Comment: What prevents you from using an RDF parser like [Jena](http://jena.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: Those parsers do not seem to have any "character validation" methods

Comment: If it's an encoding issue, maybe you can use this overload of [InputStreamReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29) to provide input to your parser.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be an encoding issue, since all characters but a few(less than 10) are recognized. What is more, I've used Jena for RDF parsing, but I got some unuseful errors(points where there is no actual problem).

Answer (score 0):

any XML contains encoding property in the header. And it's UTF-8 is default. If your XML contains bytes which can't be recognized with SAX parser, so you have not "well-formed" XML. Another way is tell correct charset/encoding to InputStreamReader you use.